# PHP array asociativos

Tags: php, array

Estoy intentando crear un array de una consulta mysql y me estoy volviendo loca.
Esa consulta me devuelve varias máquinas por centros. Y quiero hacer un array con los centros que haya y dentro de cada centro las distintas máquinas

```
foreach ($maquinas as $row){
        $centros['centros'][$row->id_centro] = $row->nombre;                
}
```

Hasta aquí bien, pero ya no sé como meterme dentro de cada centro para crear un array con las distintas máquinas.

Esta es la consulta mysql:

```
SELECT maquinas.*, centro.* from maquinas JOIN centro_maquinas ON centro_maquinas.id_maquina = maquinas.id_maquina JOIN centro ON centro.id_centro = centro_maquinas.id_centro ORDER BY id_centro
```

Devuelve varias filas cada una con el id del centro, el id de la maquina...

Comment: buenas @lagonzalez. Puedes poner la consulta que haces para ver como pueden estar llegando los datos en el array maquinas?

Comment: Es una consulta mysql y sería : SELECT `maquinas`.*, `centro`.*
from `maquinas`
JOIN `centro_maquinas` ON `centro_maquinas`.`id_maquina` = `maquinas`.`id_maquina` 
JOIN `centro` ON `centro`.`id_centro` = `centro_maquinas`.`id_centro` 
ORDER BY `id_centro` , lo que me devuelve varias filas cada una cn el id del centro, el id de la maquina...

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que el array $maquinas tiene el id del centro, el de la maquina y el nombre de maquina, creo que podrias hacer algo como:

```
foreach($maquinas as $row) {
    $centros['centros'][$row->id_centro][] = $row->nombre;
}
```

es decir, te faltaria el array final [] para que a medida que vamos pasando por cada fila, añada el elemento dentro de ese array (con el key $row->id_centro)

Destacar que esta solución supone que tus filas son del tipo:

> ```
> id_fila    id_centro   id_maquina   nombre
>    1          1            1          nombre_maquina1
>    2          1            2          nombre_maquina2
>    3          2            5          nombre_maquina3
>    4          2            6          nombre_maquina6
> ```

Comment: Creo que así me lo hace perfecto! Muchas gracias!